# timestamp time differential calculation in query on postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp, fastapi, timestamp-with-timezone

I have the following function to update data in postgresql table using `fastapi` python framework

using the [databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/) with sqlalchemy [sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/)

```
def check_token(reset_token: str):
    query = "SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE is_active=True AND reset_token=:reset_token AND expired_in >= :current_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes'"
    return database.fetch_one(query, values={"reset_token": reset_token, "current_time": datetime.utcnow()})
```

but am getting the following error

```
asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedFunctionError: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= interval

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

> funny thing is this works fine by the way

```
def create_token(email: str, reset_token: str):
    query = "INSERT INTO tokens VALUES (nextval('tokens_id_seq'), :email, :reset_token, True, :expired_in)" return 
    database.execute(query, values={"email": email, "reset_token": reset_token, "expired_in": datetime.utcnow()})
```

above works for creating the `reset_token`, but not when trying to check it if it has not expired using the `60 minutes` time diff

how do i fix this?

the `expired_in` column of the `tokens` table is of type `timestamp` in the table schema structure

and current value in the table is

```
expired_in
---------------------------
2021-08-16 18:08:40.169969
```

here is more information about the `tokens` table

```
Column |    Type  | Comment
======================================
id  integer Auto Increment [nextval('tokens_id_seq')]   
email   character varying(254)  
reset_token character varying(256) NULL 
is_active   boolean 
expired_in  timestamp NULL
```

Comment: What Python driver/framework are you using to run the above? Add as update to your question. Looks to me like `:current_time` is being ignored and you are ending up with: `select '2021-08-16 12:02:00'::timestamp >=  interval '60 minutes'; ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= interval`

Comment: fastapi...updated in question

Comment: what do you mean by `:current_time` is being ignored? what will be the way to solve?

Comment: By providing more information. I don't use FastAPI, but a quick scan of the docs shows that what you are doing is not standard. Looks like you are dropping down into the ORM directly. So what ORM? Where is `database.fetchone()` coming from?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but shouldn't match the names of the parameter the ones used in your query (including **:**)? Another possibility is, [current_time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) get's the current time without date in postgresql and this would give you as a result an interval. So try to give your parameter another name.

Comment: @Steeeve, no on the `current_time`: `select '2021-08-16 12:02:00'::timestamptz >=  current_time - interval '60 minutes'; ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone >= time with time zone`. Different error. My suspicion is that the OP missed a step namely `execute(query, values={"reset_token": reset_token, "current_time": datetime.utcnow()})`.

Comment: `UPDATED` i added the full table structure to the question

Comment: The issue is not with the table it is with your method of running the query.  Please answer the questions I asked in my previous comment and add as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for clarifying. I wasn't sure and cannot test right now.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver using https://pypi.org/project/databases/ ORM with https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/ updated in question

Comment: According to this [Query](https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/) should it not be `await database.fetch_one(query=query, ...)`? And given that `await` is async who knows what `return` is going to do. Honestly an async framework over an ORM framework over an API framework seems to me a recipe for mistakes.

Comment: the await is passed from router using the function..so issue is not await...i think i have posted all i can regarding this issue...again it is all about what is solution to this...also error is there...issue is not await

Comment: `an async framework over an ORM framework over an API framework seems to me a recipe for mistakes` so what will be solution to using fastapi with postgresql then? you dont want to wait to get result of queries?

Comment: You will need to look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database, though I'm pretty sure you are going to see something like:`select '2021-08-16 12:02:00'::timestamp >=  interval '60 minutes';`.  You will then need to work back from there to figure out why the stack is not passing the correct query in.

Comment: logs does not show you values..it just shows `$1`, `$2` in place of the values `2021-08-16 19:34:34.075 UTC [5547] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE is_active=True AND reset_token=$2 AND expired_in >= $1 - INTERVAL '60 minutes'`

Comment: Does it show an error message and if so what is the full text?

Comment: What happens if you delete your parameter :current_time and use localtimestamp instead? `expired_in >= localtimestamp - INTERVAL '60 minutes'`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver error from postgresql logs `ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= interval at character 78
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` same error reported by fastapi

Comment: @Steeeve this worked `expired_in >= localtimestamp - INTERVAL '60 minutes'` so seems when during time calculation best to add the time inside the query itself like a string and postgresql understands it then...is that correct?

Comment: @Steeeve will accept your answer if you post that in the answer section..thanks for your help

Comment: You are not doing a time calculation you are doing a timestamp/datetime, that is a distinction you need to be aware of. I would say you need to rename your parameter from `current_time` to something that does not conflict with the Postgres `current_time`  function.  Somewhere that is causing confusion.

Comment: Just for sure: did you try it with another parameter name? And my next try would be changing the order of parameters (putting reset_token at the and of the WHERE clause).

Comment: Removing the parameter is not a solution for me, the server could run in another time zone.

Comment: @Steeeve can you paste the full sql query with the parameter name of choice for me to run? that way am clear what you mean here is current one => `"SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE is_active=True AND reset_token=:reset_token AND expired_in >= :current_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes'"`

Comment: Simply use anything other than ':current_time'. For example ':cur_time'.

Comment: @Steeeve changed all `:current_time` to `:cur_time` and still same error..does not work

Comment: What the... ?! It's getting very strange... Are there any constraints in the fetch_one method regarding parameter values? Could it be that it accepts only one parameter? I can't find any documentation for this method. I'm getting out of ideas... You could try changing the order in the where clause and the parameters accordingly: `WHERE is_active=True AND expired_in >= :cur_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes' AND reset_token=:reset_token`, than we know if the second parameter gets lost.

Comment: the time is using value of `datetime.utcnow()` so it is not a parameter getting passed to function

Comment: I have a feeling it related to this [Issue](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/791) from the underlying driver `asyncpg`. Which by the way says: 'Don't use utcnow()'.  I would file an issue there on this particular problem. Using stock `psycopg2` I have no issues: cur.execute("select %(current_time)s  AT time zone 'UTC' >= (%(current_time)s at time zone 'UTC' - interval '60 minutes')", {"current_time": datetime.utcnow()})  cur.fetchone()  (True,)
`

Comment: yeah from what i have seen..seems whenever you want to do time calculation (like subtract minutes, hours etc) in sql query..postgresql expects it in the sql query itself  and not from a variable..which is why when i used `expired_in >= localtimestamp - INTERVAL '60 minutes'` it worked...this is particular to time calculation again..everything else it allows variable but not when doing time addition/subtraction

Comment: No that is wrong as my example shows. I have been using variables to supply time/datetimes/dateranges/intervals across a variety of projects over a number of years with no issues, other then mistakes on my part. The problem is with your particular setup and from the looks of it the `asyncpg` driver.

Comment: @uberrebu how are you inserting/updating records in this table? Why don't you have issues there if the problem is related to datetime parameters?

Comment: @Steeeve inserting and updating works fine because again there is no time calculation like `- INTERVAL '60 minutes'` for example...so those work fine...like i explained earlier the issue comes when i am doing the time diff in the sql query

Comment: pretty much the issue is here `:current_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes'`

Comment: So if you remove ` - INTERVAL '60 minutes'` from your query you don't get an error (even if the results would be incorrect)? I don't think so, but in my time zone is very late and I'm very tired...

Comment: nopes...all works fine until the time diff calculation is in query...so the devil in all this is `- INTERVAL '60 minutes'`

Comment: @Steeeve yeah get some rest...can always continue later..thanks for your help and effort..appreciate it

Comment: No the issue is with `:current_time`, it is not being properly passed through. Go the `asyncpg` issue I posted earlier and read through it. Then create your own issue pointing at this question. That is where the answer is going to come from.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yeah gotcha...just saying when compared to like regular insert/update queries..but yeah you might be right it could be an `asyncpg` issue

Comment: It makes no difference if the query is a select, insert or update, if it takes a parameter for a data value they will be handled the same.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this works for example `query = "INSERT INTO tokens VALUES (nextval('tokens_id_seq'), :email, :reset_token, True, :expired_in)"
return database.execute(query, values={"email": email, "reset_token": reset_token, "expired_in": datetime.utcnow()})` cc @Steeeve

Comment: added to question for others to see